# Connecting to MySQL Database (hosted in Heroku) from Excel VBA

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, heroku

I'm hosting the MySQL database in Heroku. I created a connection from Excel with 'MySQL for Excel' add-in, but I want to establish a connection from Excel with VBA code.

I get

> Access denied for user 'user' to database 'database'

My VBA code, but I think the reason for the error is somewhere else (privileges, database settings, etc... ).

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Set con = New ADODB.Connection

Dim strConn As String

strConn = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};SERVER=serverName;DATABASE=databaseName;USER=username;PASSWORD=password"

con.Open strConn
```

Comment: If you can connect with add-in look at the mysql.user table for allowed hosts and privileges.

Answer (score 0):

For exammple, here is a piece of code by using mariaDB, btw you have to install corresponding driver for database:

```
host_address = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MariaDB ODBC 3.0 Driver};" _
                           & "SERVER=" & host_address & ";" _
                           & " DATABASE=databasename;" _
                           & "UID=username;PWD=password; OPTION=3"

conn.Open
strSQL ="....."
....
```